# sbt unable to import apache library

Tags: scala

i am trying to setup a simple kafka consumer app , which consumes messages from secure HTTPS kafka cluster .

here is my sbt build file .

```
version := "0.1"
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "3.2.0" % "provided"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "6.1.0-ccs"
d
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"
```

my actual consumer code is ..

```
package main.scala.kafka
import java.util
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
object consumer extends App {




  val TOPIC="amg-dev-time"

  val  props = new Properties()
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "kafka-localhost.net:9093")

  props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("group.id", "amlng-dev-realtime")

  val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

  consumer.subscribe(util.Collections.singletonList(TOPIC))

  while(true){
    val records=consumer.poll(100)
    for (record<-records.asScala){
      println(record)
    }
  }
}
```

when i run the above setup i am getting
**object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer**

help me fix this and help me with an example on how to connect to secure kafka cluster to consume messages in scala.

upon refreshing sbt build file.. i am getting ..

````
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/h0j020h/.ivy2/localorg.apache.kafka/kafka_2.13/6.1.0-ccs/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.13/6.1.0-ccs/kafka_2.13-6.1.0-ccs.pom
[error]   not found: https://repository.com/content/repositories/pangaea_releases/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.13/6.1.0-ccs/kafka_2.13-6.1.0-ccs.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:6.1.0-ccs
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: /Users/h0j020h/.ivy2/localorg.apache.kafka/kafka_2.13/6.1.0-ccs/ivys/ivy.xml
[error]   download error: Caught javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target) while downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.13/6.1.0-ccs/kafka_2.13-6.1.0-ccs.pom
[error]   not found: https://repository.com/content/repositories/pangaea_releases/org/apache/kafka/kafka_2.13/6.1.0-ccs/kafka_2.13-6.1.0-ccs.pom
[error] Total time: 30 s, completed 19-Oct-2021, 6:21:47 pm
[info] shutting down sbt server```
````

Comment: Did you reloaded your **sbt** session and your IDE after adding the libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka 6.1.0-ccs is hosted on Confluent.

Try to add:

```
resolvers += "confluent" at "https://packages.confluent.io/maven/"
```

It should solve the problem (example on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3QZMBxpFSI2cNXmrSdZ46w))